# Django and python - use variable value as model's name

Tags: python, django, django-models

In variable called *object_type* I store values like: *Profile* or *Company* which are names of models available in the app. Both models has field called *uuid*.

I need to something like this:

```
get_object_or_404(object_type, uuid=uuid_from_request)
```

how can I pass object_type value (Profile or Company) to query correct model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a dictionary that map model names to model classes:

```
object_types = {'Profile': Profile, 'Company': Compnay}

...

get_object_or_404(object_types[object_type], uuid=uuid_from_request)
```

Or using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
import app.models

get_object_or_404(getattr(app.model, object_type), uuid=uuid_from_request)
```

Comment: About first option: type is stored in another object attribute. I am not sure  how to use in my case.

Comment: @dease, What another object?

Answer (score 1):

In django all model types are stored in magical cache, so you might use this cache to get model types, like that:

```
 from django.db.models.loading import get_model
 Model = get_model("your_app_name", "Profile")
 get_object_or_404(object_type, uuid=uuid_from_request)
```